# packageDebug > Failed to seal APK on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i added facebook sdk and AndroidMidi and i think i did it ok including dependencies and add model dependency on project structure
that is my build file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':AndroidMidi')
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

i can't get it running,
i get this error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
Failed to seal APK,
help?

**EDIT**
thats settings.gradle

```
include ':facebook', ':AndroidMidi'
```

stacktrace log returns:
:packageDebug Failed and same error
*not enough rep to upload picture*

Comment: this `apply plugin: 'android'` looks weird, what version of gradle are you using? (usually the value for this plugin is `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`)

Comment: also, post your `settings.gradle` file

Comment: the `apply plugin: 'android'` is the old ID of the plugin but that form is still supported for now. You might try building from the command line, with the `--stacktrace` flag if necessary, to see the full exception that's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the file `MidiPlayer/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` fixed it for me.

See: https://github.com/tkirshboim/btmidi/commit/7486ccbf17a6c2c36ef642bfb03fb9e13352c369

Comment: Thanks...kirsh300.